# RabbitMQ dangle connections not closing

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, connection, amqp, channel

Recently deployed `RabbitMQ 3.7.7 erlang 21.0.1`. Connection, channel and socket descriptors keep on increasing, see it on the management page. In an hour it grows by around **250**. Not many details in the log. Can someone suggest the steps to troubleshoot? The same code base deployment on other VM does not have this issue. Using 3 brokers federated.

In log I see short lived many connections with Steps
`accepting -> connection -> closed`.
It appears to me that publish causing this error.

Comment: What has C# to do with the question at hand? Is it even related to programming? Isn't this more of configuration task of server components in a professional setting?

Comment: Application connecting to RabbitMQ developed in C# programming language. This is just for reference that I am getting issue when programmatically connecting to RabbitMQ. Not sure what configuration to be made on broker if any. I want to pin point which connection source, if buggy, not closing connection while publishing or subscribing. Any further help appreciated. when i did netstat, saw that many connection being held by erl.exe. It keeps on growing and eventually making system slower and reaching to crash threshold/limit. I increased limit for now to 50K+.